# IIS rewrite fails

Tags: c#, iis

I want to rewrite this URL:
    `https://localhost/My/Test.dll`
 into this:
    `https://localhost:444/Api/Test`
(It is a GET mvc action)

I use this rule:

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for Thing 2" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="*/My/Test.dll" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost:444/Api/Test" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Any idea why I get a 404 errror when hitting `https://localhost/My/Test.dll` with my browser?
I have URL Rewrite installed.
Do I also need to install Application Request Routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are attempting to match is not the query string, but the path in the URL. Try the following instead:

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for Thing 2" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="My/Test\.dll" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="Api/Test" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: This gives me: "HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found. The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it." I have a second rule after this one, but I doubt it affects the 1st anyway.

Comment: Changing it partly into this: `<match url="*/My/Test.dll" />` I get a : "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found. The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." (`https://localhost:444/Api/Test` works on my browser)

Comment: Don't introduce the `*/` prefix. The string that is passed the the regex checker does not include the initial `/`.

Comment: Aha! Thanks! I also changed it into this and it works: `<action type="Rewrite" url="Api/Test" appendQueryString="false" />`. It seems it dislikes absolute urls... Please update your answer. I will mark it as correct. :)